# Updating my model then re-evaluate IsValid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm passing in some values to my controller action and everything is binding up fine. There will be two properties missing from the form POST by design.

I am then setting the missing values but then I want to validate the model and it is still saying false since it looks like the ModelState hasn't caught up with my changes.

```
[HttpPost, Authorize]
public ActionResult Thread(int id, string groupSlug, Comment comment, string submitButton)
{
  comment.UserID = UserService.UID;
  comment.IP = Request.UserHostAddress;
  UpdateModel(comment); //throws invalidoperationexception
  if (ModelState.IsValid) // returns false if i skip last line
  {
    //save and stuff
    //redirect
  }
  //return view
}
```

What is the cleanest way to pat the ModelState on the head and tell it that everything will be okay whilst still validating everything else that was bound from the user's POST

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If the missing Values are required for your model but will not be provided until after binding you may need to clear the errors caused by those two values from the `ModelState`.

```
[HttpPost, Authorize]
public ActionResult Thread(int id, string groupSlug, Comment comment, string submitButton)
{
  comment.UserID = UserService.UID;
  comment.IP = Request.UserHostAddress;

  //add these two lines
  ModelState["comment.UserID"].Errors.Clear();
  ModelState["comment.IP"].Errors.Clear();

  UpdateModel(comment); //throws invalidoperationexception
  if (ModelState.IsValid) // returns false if i skip last line
  {
    //save and stuff
    //redirect
  }
  //return view
}
```

Comment: this answers the question. However I think my architecture is what is at fault. I have gone back and changed the model

Comment: Doesn't appear to be the solution in ASP.NET Core 1.0.0

Answer (score 9):

I'm using the ASP.NET Core 1.0.0 and async binding and for me the solution was to use ModelState.Remove and pass the property name (without object name).

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Submit([Bind("AerodromeID,ObservationTimestamp,RawObservation")] WeatherObservation weatherObservation)
{
    weatherObservation.SubmitterID = this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
    weatherObservation.RecordTimestamp = DateTime.Now;

    ModelState.Remove("SubmitterID");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(weatherObservation);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Aerodrome");
    }
    return View(weatherObservation);
}
```

Comment: Work on ASP.NET 5 as well

Answer (score 2):

Before .NET Core you can use **`Validate(TEntity entity)`** function of controller. But first you have to clear existing ModelState errors.
Suppose you set a missing required property to entity.

```
  ModelState.Clear();
  Validate(entity);
  if (!ModelState.IsValid) {}
```

With Core you can use `TryValidateModel` instead of  `ModelState.IsValid`
see thiis: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

You can't use **UpdateModel(comment)** in .net core which is used in asp.net.
In **Dot net core** you can use **TryValidateModel**. Before calling it, you need to reset your modelState.

```
    //you may need to put any logical change on model
    model.IsDefault = model.IsDefault??false;//I was having IsDefault as empty string
    //clear the model state
    ModelState.Clear();
    
    if(TryValidateModel(model)){
        //your code
    }else{
        //handle the invalid model
    }
```

Or you can remove the field which you don't want to put in validation with

```
ModelState.Remove("FieldName");
```

The **FieldName** can the name of the key in the model or if the field is a class object's property then field name will be like bellow

```
ModelState.Remove("ClassName.FieldName");
```