# Can't update ModelState after modifying it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the exact same problem described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389441/updating-my-model-then-re-evaluate-isvalid) question. My view does not provide some data in my controller. so in the controller before i validate the ModelState i re-assign that value manually. then when i try to update the ModelState it shows error `'The model of type /*my model*/ could not be updated.'`

Here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateEntry(NewEntryViewModel model)
{
    model.SexList = new SelectList(_newEntryService.GetSexList(), "Key", "Value");
    model.DoctorList = new SelectList(_refDocService.GetDocList(), "Key", "Value");
    model.TestList = _testService.GetAllTests();
    model.Patient.Serial = _newEntryService.GenerateSerial();

    //ModelState["TestList"].Errors.Clear();
    //ModelState.Remove("TestList");
    UpdateModel(model);  //error shows here

    var errors = ModelState
        .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
        .Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors })
        .ToArray();

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //do something
        return View("NewEntry", model);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("NewEntry");
}
```

I have tried with those commented out lines, each of them at once. but the error still shows. thats the solution i found in the question given at the top. so how do i solve it? btw TestList is just an IEnumerable of a domain class like `public IEnumerable<Admin_Test> TestList { get; set; }`

Comment: I would recommend not doing this.  You should validate the view model as far as possible (with [Required] and [Range] etc)  but the 'difficult' referential checks should be part of your service/business layer, not the view model or the controller.

Comment: well, there is no [Required] or any other attributes on the `TestList` property. besides in the view i didn't even use `@Html.DropDownListFor`. i created the `<select>` element manually because i needed to store some other data in the `<option>` tags. so actually i can't understand why ModelState is trying to validate it.

Comment: Are you trying to validate the viewmodel coming or are you getting it ready to push out again?  If the latter, just move the first 4 lines to just before the return View("NewEntry", model) line.  A view model should not have complex validation checks, just simple ones.

Comment: i need to validate the ViewModel before pushing it. and yes i am not using any kind of validation attributes in my viewmodel class. my viewmodel class contains multiple domain classes (EF). in those domain classes i used validation attributes. besides, `TestList` is not even a part of any domain class. so it should not have any `data-val` attribute rendered right?

Comment: Your view model should NOT contain any domain classes.  Each API function should have it's own input view model and output view model.  These view models should contain just the things that the one view requires (in a format that the UI finds easy to manage).  That is why you are having the problems you are.  You need to investigate how MVC (model/view/controller) works., Separate your app into layers that communicate via independent DTOs.

Answer (score -1):

so i finally found a solution but i do not recommend it. i do not need to update modelstate, i just need to remove the error from the modelstate dictionary. so i only used `ModelState.Remove("TestList");`. i did it because `TestList` is not part of any domain class which needs to be validated. i did not use `@Html.DropDownListFor` for `TestList`, nor it has any `[Required]` or any other types of attributes inside the ViewModel class. I only used attributes in my domain classes. so i dont even know why `TestList` is rendering `data-val` attributes in the view (which maybe causes the ModelState trying to validate it). as i was sure, i forcefully removed only this validation from ModelState dictionary.